# MUI V5 extended row different background alternative row color is not working

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I am using MUI v5 to display data in Collapsible table with below code but all rows bgcolor is showing as grey instead of alternative row. Could you please help us how to show alternative row color in MUI Collapsible table.

I have added below snippet for odd number row.

```js
const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
    backgroundColor: "grey",
  },
  // hide last border
  "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
    border: 0,
  },
}));
```

[MUI Docs](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.15.14/docs/data/material/components/table/CollapsibleTable.tsx)

I am expecting alternative row color should be different in collapsible table.

Comment: I am able to resolve this by passing row index to <Row> component